# Excel VBA or non VBA : How do I perform matching between two sheets which have column names and rows in jumbled order?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel and VBA. I am attempting to find the mismatch between two sheets (Sheet A & Sheet B), and highlight the differences in Sheet A when there are mismatches of data . Both sheets have data from A1:Y300.

The challenge is the columns between two sheets are not in the same order. For example, column "car" is in C1 in Sheet A while column "car" is in B1 in Sheet B.

And the rows are not in same order also. Both sheets have employee ID in A1, and for instance, employee ID 007 can be row 2 in Sheet A, while same employee ID is in row 3 in Sheet B.

To perform mismatches, I was thinking to **validate the columns names between two sheets first**, to check if columns in Sheet A exists in Sheet B which can be in different order. After validation, checking of mismatches will commence. But not sure how to perform this function.

If I apply conditional formatting, A1<>SheetB!A1, and highlight the mismatches, will this able to correctly perform mismatches, or do I need to sort the column names and row names alphabetically first? 
What should I do to correctly highlight the mismatches?

Comment: The thing you need is to find in what column is (for example) Emp_ID header in Sheet B. I think it will be easier if you can give a screen shot of sheet-A and sheet-B, enough with 4 column header with 10 rows of data for example. I don't quite understand on what you mean "mismatch data"... do you mean (for example) the Emp_ID is id-007 and the Item is Car in sheet-A ... but in sheet-B, item with id-007 is Airplane. Something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Designate one of your tabs as "Leader" and the other as "Follower", it doesn't matter which is which. Now, ... (schematic) ...

```
For Each Column In Leader.Columns
    Find the matching column in Follower
    For Row = 2 To Leader.Column.End.Row
        Find the Value of Cells(Row, Column) in Follower.Column
        If Find Is Nothing Then Mark Leder.Cells(Row, Column)
    Next Row
Next Column
```

The result will be that the Leader tab has all items marked which were not found in the matching column on the Follower tab. All unmarked items were found. To mark the items in Follower which are not available in Leader repeat the process with the two sheets switched.

Comment: have a look to scripting.dictionary. then you can make a ditionary whichj hold the headers and column numbers. Then use the dictionary to get the header number of the second table which will match.